# How to get values of dynamically generated textarea inputs with php

Tags: php, html

I'm having a challenge with a mini project I'm working on and have googled for a solution for hours without a headway.
I have a column in my database table whose contents are generated by exploding a previous form inputs(separated by comma in the table). Now I need to get inputs (from users) for these values using textarea in a form. These inputs will be in arrays depending on the number of contents fetched from the db in the first place and then stored in another column in my table. The issue here is that each time I submit the form I get an undefined index notice for the name of the values in the textarea field, which is test-col [].
please see my code below:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'myDb');
    $users_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tests FROM bal WHERE users_id = '$users_id'");
    if ($res){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $tests = explode(',', $row['tests']);   
            foreach($tests as $test){
                if ($test ==""){
                    continue;
                }
                echo '<div class="test-res" style="margin-top:10px;">
                          <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for= "test-col" class="form-label col-md-2">'.$test.' test</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-10">
                                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="test-col[]" placeholder="Test result"> </textarea>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>';
                '<br /> <br />';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-5" name="sub-res">Send Result</button>
          </form>';
?>

//to insert textarea values in db
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub-res'])){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'myDb');
        foreach ($_POST ['test-col'] as $values){
            $test_results = implode("<br>", $values);
        }
        $ins = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO bal (results) VALUES
 ('$test_results') WHERE users_id = '$users_id'");
        if (!$ins){
            die(mysqli_error());
        }
        else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully sent</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I edited to format your code so that it becomes readable. The way it was formatted, it was completely impossible to read. I recommend that you always format your code correctly, both for the people reading it and for yourself.

Comment: Thank you @ Donald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two forms - one in your `while`/`foreach` statement, and then one below. If you're submitting the second form, it won't contain values from the first.

Wrap the while in the form instead;

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php       
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'myDb');
$users_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);  
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tests FROM bal WHERE users_id =
 '$users_id'");
if ($res){  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){    
        $tests = explode(',', $row['tests']);       
        foreach($tests as $test){           
            if ($test =="") {
                continue;   
            }       
            echo '<div class="test-res" style="margin-top:10px;"><div class="form-group">
              <label for= "test-col" class="form-label col-md-2">'.$test.' test</label><div class="col-md-10"><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="test-col[]" placeholder="Test result"> </textarea></div></div></div>';     
           '<br /> <br />' ;    
        } 
    } 
}
?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-5" name="sub-res">Send Result</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @thebluefox. i tried iterating and display the inputs on my screen on submit, this is what i get "test-col: Arraytest-res:". However, what i want is to fetch those values and implode them into my table column. How do i go about that please?

Comment: Still waiting for your assistance please